Neighborhood filter of a filter?
I've been brushing up on point-set topology these last weeks, with Wikipedia as my principal source of information. In particular, I discovered filters and their use in topology.
Playing with the different notions, I figured that it makes sense to generalize the traditional notions of neighborhood filters (neighborhood filter of a point, of a set) by defining the neighborhood filter of a filter. Indeed, this allows to formulate some results in an elegant fashion. So now, I am curious whether this is a classic construction that can be found in topology textbooks. (I would guess so, but how classic?)
Let me briefly explain the construct. Let $E$ be a pretopological space, and ${\cal N}_x$ denote its neighborhood filter at every point $x\in E$. Given a filter $\cal F$ on $E$, define its neighborhood filter as
$$ {\cal N}({\cal F}):= \bigcup_{B\in\cal F} \bigcap_{x\in B} {\cal N}_x$$
Actually, it is easy to see that the union over $B\in\cal F$ can be replaced by a union over $B\in\cal B$ for any filter basis $\cal B$ of the filter $\cal F$.
Note that this definition extends the traditional definitions for neighborhood filters. The neighborhood filter of a set $A$ is recovered as
$${\cal N}_A = {\cal N}(\{A\}^{\uparrow E}) = \bigcap_{x\in A} {\cal N}_x$$
and the neighborhood filter of a point $x$ is recovered as
${\cal N}_x = {\cal N}(\{\{x\}\}^{\uparrow E})$.
This extended formulation has some nice properties. In a pretopological space, we have

For every filter $\cal F$, $\quad {\cal N}(\cal F) \leq \cal F$
For every family of filters $\{{\cal F}_j\}_{j\in\cal J}$, $\quad {\cal N}(\bigcap_{j\in\cal J}{\cal F}_j)=\bigcap_{j\in\cal J}{\cal N}({\cal F}_j)$

Conversely, any operator ${\cal N}:{\rm Filters}(E)\to{\rm Filters}(E)$ satisfying properties 1 and 2 defines a pretopology. Indeed, the `usual' neighborhood filters are recovered as ${\cal N}_x:={\cal N}(\{\{x\}\}^{\uparrow E})$.
Furthermore, the link with the interior operator of the pretopology is the following:
$$ B\in {\cal N(F)} \quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad B^\circ \in {\cal F}$$
Finally, it is easy to see that this pretopological space is topological if, and only if, the extended operator ${\cal N}$ is idempotent, i.e., it verifies

${\cal N}\circ{\cal N}={\cal N}$

So my question is: Is this a classic construct in traditional expositions of point-set topology? If yes, in what textbooks? Are there other interesting properties/formulations using this `extended' neighborhood operator?

This is a relatively classic construction and is discussed in the following textbooks:

Convergence Foundations of Topology, by Dolecki and Mynard
A Royal Road to Topology, by Dolecki

In these books the construction is called the contour of $\mathcal{N}$, but I believe there are also other names in the literature.
Your property (3) is linked to the notion of diagonality. It is also given in equation V.3.12 of "Convergence Foundations of Topology".
